# Terminal wont let me login

Tags: virtual-console

My terminal wont open up at all. After doing some snooping on the web I figured out to go to the virtual terminal and fix it. The problem is, that when i type my username and password, it says it's incorrect. I've tried my login info many times and it still doesn't work. I know how to fix it and everything. It is just this that is stopping me. I could really use some help on this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: yeah thank you so much